# cannot read static files after deploying my project on pythonanywhere PYTHON DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I dont know if I did this right but during development phase I placed all my static files on my project's main directory, it looks like this:

myproject

- myapp
- manage.py
- myproject

  ```
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  ...
  ```
- **static**

  ```
  - css
       - somecssfile.css
  - js
       - somejsfile.js
  ...
  ```
- templates

now my settings.py file looks like this:

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

after I deployed my project into pythonanywhere I added `STATIC_ROOT`:

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/jeremiramos/cvs/staticfiles/'

it does copy my static files to `staticfiles` folder when I do `collectstatic` on pythonanywhere console but it cannot read/load the static files I used on each and every page including `admin` page.

and my staticfiles settings on pythonanywhere looks like this:
[image]

I checked my console and I got some errors:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://jeremiramos.pythonanywhere.com/static/css/index.css/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I've tried checking the forums of pythonanywhere.com but it doesn't seem to help.

Can anyone please explain what did I do wrong and what should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `http://jeremiramos.pythonanywhere.com/static/css/index.css` loads the actual file, it means that static file mappings are OK. Trying the url with trailing slash (as in the error message you've shown) gives 404 and MIME type error message might be a symptom of it. Remove trailing slash from the url and check if that solves the issue.

Comment: right, my problem is with my code, how I access my css file seems to be the problem. I removed the trailing slash and it worked. Thank you so much!